# Transparent redirect to port 8080

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a few web applications available on my server on port 8080.

As some of my users can't reach port 8080 due to their firewall, I'd like to set a redirection on my apache server. Il would like the following URL

```
http://dev2.test.com/tomcat/somewebapp/restofthepath
```

to display what is accessible at

```
http://dev2.test.com:8080/somewebapp/restofthepath
```

Of course I don't want users typing the first address to see the second one.

I added the following `.htaccess` file in `/var/www` :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(tomcat)
RewriteRule ^/tomcat/(.*)$ http://dev2.test.com:8080/$1 [P,QSA,L]
```

But I get this error in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` :

```
[Tue Oct 09 15:23:06 2012] [error] File does not exist:  proxy:http://dev2.test.com:8080/tomcat/
```

Could you please tell me what I should do ?

Comment: Just remove the the P flag from your rewrite rule.

Comment: @alk I get this response "The requested URL /tomcat/ was not found on this server."

Comment: What do you need the `$` sign for in `RewriteRule ^/tomcat/(.*)$`?

Comment: It doesn't seem needed but removing it changes nothing. After many tests I'm under the impression that the first part or the RewriteRule doesn't match with my URL. Even `^/tomcat/` doesn't seem to match.

Comment: Not sure, but did you try: `RewriteRule ^/tomcat(.*) http://dev2.test.com:8080$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: Yes, without success. I'll try to enable mod_proxy following lanzz's advice (and Nir Levy too).

Comment: Yes, I just started to think about this solution ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should probably be using [`mod_proxy`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#forwardreverse) instead of `mod_rewrite`.

```
ProxyPass /tomcat http://dev2.test.com:8000/
ProxyPassReverse /tomcat http://dev2.test.com:8000/
```

EDIT :

This configuration must be in httpd.conf. It may be in a VirtuaHost section or at the root of the file.

You have to enable mod_proxy. This could be done using

```
LoadModule  proxy_module         /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule  proxy_http_module    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Comment: Most likely, in the `<VirtualHost>` block for your site.

Comment: OK, it works. Not in the VirtualHost section, I don't have one. If you don't disagree I'll add a few things in your answer to precise the configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Doing what you did will only send a redirect to port 8080 to the user (which they can't use). You need to use [apache mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) or a different proxy server.

```
ProxyPass /foo http://foo.example.com/bar
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://foo.example.com/bar
```

Comment: Can you tell me in what file I should write this ?

Comment: Context: server config, virtual host, directory. See the doc.

Comment: Thanks Nir. Being 32 secondes late means you're not accepted but of course you get an upvote.

Comment: @dystroy 32 seconds is the story of my life :) hope I helped just a bit.