# XMLHttpRequest Access Control Allow Origin when url is not complete

Tags: php, ajax, http

Sometimes when I submit ajax requests I get this error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.mysite.com/go/submit. Origin http://mysite.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Here are solutions I thought about:

```
* Add the allow origin rule everywhere?
* Write .htaccess to always redirect to full url
* Use this method http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/
```

How should I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) means you cannot analyze data (json, html, image, etc.) that are coming from another "origin" (domain, port) than yours.

Note that

> The term "origin" is defined using the domain name, application layer
>   protocol, and (in most browsers) port number of the HTML document
>   running the script

A solution is to set, on the server serving the other data, [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control) explicitly allowing the access :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

So you must have control of the server serving the data you embed as soon as you're not just displaying them.

A somewhat indirect solution is to let the browser think there is only one origin, by putting on your server a proxy. On apache you don't need .htaccess but `mod_proxy`. If you want to install such a proxy, you may be interested by [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801246/transparent-redirect-to-port-8080) (in fact you'd probably be more interested by the answer which helped me set such a proxy on one of my servers).

If your only problem is people typing mysite.com instead of www.mysite.com and you have only one server, you may simply use .htaccess to rewrite the URL :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: But why is it considering http://www.mysite.com/go/submit. to be different domain than http://mysite.com

Comment: www.mysite.com may not be the same host as mysite.com. If that's the same machine, you may solve the problem by fixing the links.

Comment: my issue is that it's the main page so sometimes people for shortcut just type in the url mysite.com instead of the full url, if they click any other link on the site they will get the full url but I don't control the first page when they type it.

Comment: should I just do header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *mysite.com');

Comment: Yes, you may add this header. But see edit if the problem is only people forgetting the "www" : you may rewrite the url. Both solutions work.

Comment: The problem is only when I don't have www